# Upload the file, view and rewriting the same file from that same page in php

Tags: php

I have a form that using to upload many datas and files. If a user uploaded a file, the file have to view from the same page while clicking view button and if any changes, have to update the same file. I have number of file uploads in one form.

My Form is...

```
<fieldset id="pan-step4-new" class="form-style">
  <h2 class="fs-title">Please Upload Documents</h2>
  <div class="black-underline" ></div>

  <div class="col-md-4"><p>Your Passport Copy</p> </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 pan_new_pass_front_label">
      <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block" >
      <h5 id="pan_new_pass_front_label">Attach Passport Front Page</h5>
       <input type="file" name="pan_new_pass_front"     id="pan_new_pass_front" accept="image/*" />
     </label>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12  input-group">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block">
    <h5 id="pan_new_pass_back_label">Attach Passport Address Page</h5>
    <input type="file" name="pan_new_pass_back" id="pan_new_pass_back" accept="image/*" />
      </label>
      </div>

  <div class="col-md-4"><p>Your Visa Page</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 input-group">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block">
  <h5 id="pan_new_visa_label">Attach Visa Page</h5>
  <input type="file" name="pan_new_visa" id="pan_new_visa" accept="image/*" />
   </label>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 "><p>Your Residency Proof in UAE</p></div>
  <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 input-group">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block">
  <h5 id="pan_new_proof_uae_label">Attach Proof Page</h5>
  <input type="file" name="pan_new_proof_uae" id="pan_new_proof_uae" accept="image/*" />
   </label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4"><p>Your Photo</p></div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 input-group">
    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-block">
   <h5 id="pan_new_photo_label">Attach Passport Size Photo</h5>
   <input type="file" name="pan_new_photo" id="pan_new_photo" accept="image/*" />
    </label>
                      </div>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-prev btn-style previous-button-style" value="prev"  id="pan-step4-new-prev" />
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-next btn-style previous-button-style" name="pan_new_submit" value="submit" id="pan_new_submit"/>
   </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/).
It will preview your file before upload, and you can even remove the file before upload.